# Multiple/Bulk Image Upload Tutorial? Plupload etc

Tags: 7, media, files

I want my users to be able to upload multiple images at once. They need to be able to upload 60 images for one gallery and doing that one at a time is just not feasible. I've been reading other posts here and doing a ton of searches. I'm told that using the Media module and plupload (I have the javascript library and the drupal integration module installed) that I can do it, but I can't figure out how to actually make it work.

Would anyone be willing to explain it below? I've seen at least one video on youtube that shows the person clicking the Select Media button which pops up a little window, and that window has a drag and drop plupload area where they drop their images. I don't see anything like that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install [Multiupload Filefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget) and, if you're so inclined, [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget).

Make sure your PHP upload limit will allow all the files to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using http://drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676 Media Multi-select module.

Answer (score -4):

In Drupal 7 You can't add a bulk upload field to content types because it does not support CCK.   According to [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1019170) others want to do this too.  There are several side projects but nothing official.

Bulk upload only works as a stand alone tool that creates individual nodes under "create content."

Comment: This is not true.